# Regular expressions / javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for finding anything that is not a letter, and I also want to detect any white spaces in my string. I have looked at the MDN documentation, youtube videos, and stackoverflow questions, and I still don't understand. Could you point me in the right direction? Here is the jsfiddle(it is a function for palindromes.): https://jsfiddle.net/jn2tutty/71/

Here is the code:

`var regexp = /[^A-Za-z]|\s+|/g;`

Comment: White space characters are not letters, so there's no need to test for them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is correct. Your code/fiddle does not work because the strings have different casing (`Racecar` vs `racecar`).

If you also convert the `nospace` variable to lowercase, it works:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  // Good luck!
  var nospace = str.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();
                                 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- added this
  var reverse = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  var change = reverse.toLowerCase();
  console.log(change);
  var regexp = /[^A-Za-z]|\s+/g;

  var x = change.replace(regexp, "");

  if (nospace == x) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(palindrome("Race car"));
```

See [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/jn2tutty/72/).

---

Now, your code could use some other improvements.

The regex "strip everything that is not a letter" regex (`/[^A-Za-z]|\s+/g`) could be simplified to `/[^A-Za-z]/g`. But you may really not need it at all (I don't know your requirements, you may still need it if your requirements really want you to remove non-letters, not just spaces).

Your first `nospace` var only replaces the first white space from the input. Using a regex there would make it replace all of them (only do this if this is really what you wanted): `str.replace(" ", "")`  becomes `str.replace(/\s+/g, "")`.

Also, since you already removed the spaces in nospace, you could just reverse it (instead of reversing the input and later removing its spaces). And then compare it.

Also the last `if`/`else` could be simplified to just a `return` statement. The final code would look something like this:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var nospace = str.replace(/\s+/g, "").toLowerCase();
  var reverse = nospace.split('').reverse().join('').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
  //          optional, depends on your requirements -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return nospace === reverse;
}
console.log(palindrome("R a c e    c a r")); // output: true
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/jn2tutty/74/).

Comment: Yeah, good point. I was thinking on updating the answer with that remark. I think I will now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks alot. This helped tremendously. I am still learning :)

Answer (score 1):

This approach discards everything but letters and uses a for loop to reverse the string.

```
var str = ' some123 text -&';
str = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'').toLowerCase();
console.log(str);
var i,reversed = '';
for (i = str.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
        reversed += str[i];
}
if (str === reversed) {
        console.log('palindrome');
} else {
        console.log('not a palindrome');
}
```